# Como mostrar en un label el ultimo dato la fila de una base de datos

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf

Estoy trabajando en C# con conexión de base datos y quiero mostrar el ultimo dato ingresado de la tabla historial de la columna CantidadActual en un label

```
private void MostarCantidadActual()
    {
        string mostrar = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Historial ORDER BY Id DESC";

        connectionsql.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(mostrar, connectionsql);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puede que te falte añadir a que base de Datos apunta esa query, por ejemplo:

```
private void MostarCantidadActual()
{
    string mostrar = "USE HistorialDB SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Historial ORDER BY Id DESC";

    connectionsql.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(mostrar, connectionsql);

}
```

Espero que te haya sido de ayuda